# Password protecting with Htaccess results in Error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website hosted with `nearlyfreespeech` (saying it here so maybe someone who has a website hosted there can help.)

I have two files:

### .htaccess

```
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName 'Reserved Area'
 AuthUserFile /home/public/money/downloads/plugins/.htpasswd
 Require valid-user
```

### .htpasswd

I am not including anything here, as it's irrelevant.

---

The problem might be with the directory(?)
Also nearlyfreespeech's dashboard gives me those two things  -- Don't know if they can be of any help.

`Apache Site Root   /fs7d/privacy/
Apache Document Root    /fs7d/privacy/public/`

---

The problem as you read from the title is "error 500".

*I looked at the server logs and found out that the problem was actually the directory, now, question is, how do I find the proper directory to fix this error?*

***Thanks***

Comment: 500 is a server error. Ideally you would look at the server error logs. You need to take this up with the hosting company.

Comment: @jdv I looked at the server logs and found out that the problem was actually the directory, now , question is, how do i find the proper directory?

Comment: Who knows? There does not have to be a 1:1 relationship between an actual filesystem directory and a server path. They are probably using "userdir" to supply per-user hosting. But this is something you need to discuss with the hosting company. It is not a good question for SE.